# How can I find a file that contains a specific image placed in, using Mac Terminal?

Tags: mac

I need to find an .ai file that has placed in a specific image. I can't remember the file name but I do know the name of the image placed in that file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No tools exist for that.

If this `.ai` file contains the *name* of the image, which you
know (fully or partially), and if you have a tool that can search
binary files, you might use it to binary-search all your
`.ai` files for this name-string.

Some Linux tools for searching may be found in the post
[Linux Command to find Strings in Binary or non ascii file](https://serverfault.com/questions/51477/linux-command-to-find-strings-in-binary-or-non-ascii-file).